# If Div is A, B, or C, then fade OUT and fade IN Div X

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on the navigation of my portfolio website right now and Im having trouble figuring out how to add other properties to my `toggle()` function.

Its basically a filter system with 4 possible options, they are..

- All
- Interactive
- Graphic
- Audio

**I want to make it so that when you click on a button it fades out all of the other options, and fades in the corresponding content section..**

**For example - Clicking on the interactive button would do this:**

> "if all is visible, fade out, and fade in interactive" + "if graphic
>   is visible, fade out, and fade in interactive" + "if audio is visible,
>   fade out, and fade in interactive"

So that i am covering all of my bases with one button click..

I tried to add multiple IDs to the code unsuccessfully here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#filter-interactive").toggle(function() {
  $("#wrapper-thumbnails-all, #wrapper-thumbnails-graphic, #wrapper-thumbnails-audio").fadeOut(function() { $("#wrapper-thumbnails-interactive").fadeIn(); });
}, function() {
  $("#wrapper-thumbnails-interactive").fadeOut(function() { $("#wrapper-thumbnails-all").fadeIn(); });
  });
});
```

Here is basically my simplified html structure:
**Only the ALL Section starts out as visible, all others are set to Display:none;**

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper-thumbnails-all">
 Content
</div>

<div id="wrapper-thumbnails-interactive">
 Content
</div>

<div id="wrapper-thumbnails-graphic">
 Content
</div>

<div id="wrapper-thumbnails-audio">
 Content
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've try with a chackbox, this is an example, i do not know if is what you want, but see this fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgXtK/)

```
$('#wrapper-thumbnails-all').fadeIn();

$('input:checkbox').change(function(){

    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#wrapper-thumbnails-'+$(this).val()).fadeIn();
    }else{
        $('#wrapper-thumbnails-'+$(this).val()).fadeOut();
    }

});
```